# Cannot start NFS daemon

Tags: linux, nfs, centos5, daemon

I'm trying to set up a NFS share but I cant start NFS service:

```
$ service nfs start

Starting NFS services:                                     [  OK  ]
Starting NFS daemon:                                       [FAILED]

$ service nfs status

rpc.mountd is stopped
nfsd is stopped
```

Portmap is running:

```
$service portmap status

portmap (pid 6522) is running...
```

Exports contents (the real exports file has valid IP address instead of xxx.)

```
$ cat /etc/exports

/var/www/vhosts/ xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx(ro,sync)
```

`/var/log/messages` output after `service nfs start`

```
Apr 14 13:24:18 s15315044 nfsd[2483]: nfssvc: Function not implemented
```

As requested:

```
$ grep NFS /boot/config*

/boot/config-2.6.26.7rootserver-20081028a:CONFIG_NFS_FS=y
/boot/config-2.6.26.7rootserver-20081028a:CONFIG_NFS_V3=y
/boot/config-2.6.26.7rootserver-20081028a:CONFIG_NFS_V3_ACL=y
/boot/config-2.6.26.7rootserver-20081028a:CONFIG_NFS_V4=y
/boot/config-2.6.26.7rootserver-20081028a:# CONFIG_NFSD is not set
/boot/config-2.6.26.7rootserver-20081028a:CONFIG_NFS_ACL_SUPPORT=y
/boot/config-2.6.26.7rootserver-20081028a:CONFIG_NFS_COMMON=y
/boot/config-2.6.27.4rootserver-20081028a:CONFIG_NFS_FS=y
/boot/config-2.6.27.4rootserver-20081028a:CONFIG_NFS_V3=y
/boot/config-2.6.27.4rootserver-20081028a:CONFIG_NFS_V3_ACL=y
/boot/config-2.6.27.4rootserver-20081028a:CONFIG_NFS_V4=y
/boot/config-2.6.27.4rootserver-20081028a:# CONFIG_NFSD is not set
/boot/config-2.6.27.4rootserver-20081028a:CONFIG_NFS_ACL_SUPPORT=y
/boot/config-2.6.27.4rootserver-20081028a:CONFIG_NFS_COMMON=y
```

I'ts a dedicated server: CentOS release 5.7

```
$ cat /proc/version

Linux version 2.6.27.4rootserver-20081028a (root@rpmbuildd-amd64) (gcc version 4.1.2 20071124 (Red Hat 4.1.2-42)) #1 SMP Tue Oct 28 06:03:38 EDT 2008
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Run `LANG=C service nfs start` and post the real output. Also, check your logs (`/var/log/syslog` and/or `/var/log/messages`)

Comment: Updated with real output and added `messages` output

Comment: Please add OS specifics to your question (distro, version, kernel version, `grep NFS /boot/config*`, physical/virtual, VPS, ...)

Comment: Ok, done. It's a physical dedicated server.

Comment: is this a custom kernel?

Comment: Don't know. It's the distro that came with my server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, your kernel does not have the NFSD bits activated. It can be an NFS client, but not an NFS server.

`/boot/config-2.6.26.4rootserver-20081028a:# CONFIG_NFSD is not set`

You should recompile the kernel to have this enabled.

Comment: Instead of recompiling the kernel, do you believe that a `yum upgrade kernel-smp` would help?

Comment: Trying can do no harm

Comment: I've accepted the answer but I'm not going to deal with kernel recompilation, instead I'm using rsync. It seems to be a better option to transfer files from server to server.